# Difference between numpy.convolve and scipy.ndimage.convolve1d?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

What is the difference between the algorithms underlying `numpy.convolve` and `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d`?

Are there are other equivalent/similar functions in Python? Which is most appropriate for associatively implementing multivariate convolutions (more than 2 input distributions)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why does my convolution routine differ from numpy & scipy's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046795/why-does-my-convolution-routine-differ-from-numpy-scipys)

Comment: The rest of the question is off-topic for SO (requests for software and opinions)

Comment: It highlights some options in `scipy` and `numpy` but doesn't go in much detail how the two functions have a common ground (as what we would expect from alternative coded versions of the same math concept). Also would like (2) an enumeration of all other similar convolution functions across these two libraries, and (3) which of them is best for extended to the multivariate case